# Perl - Downloading multiple PDF files with date in URL into to text

Tags: perl, web-scraping

I am just a beginner and learning and trying to implement bunch of things at this moment.

I am trying to get the text from online PDF files.

I have a code that is working to download a single file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use POSIX 'strftime';
use LWP::Simple;

my $url = 'http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/CREC-2011-01-26/pdf/';
my $file = 'CREC-2011-01-26.pdf', localtime;

getstore( "$url/$file", $file );
```

I am wondering if there is a way to modify the date: say, change date to 2011-01-25 in the comment line and extract the files all for the one year period?

Also, is there a way to just get the text from the online source without downloading the files. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

To iterate over all days in the year 2011:

```
use 5.010;
use DateTime qw();

my $counter = DateTime->new(year => 2011, month => 1, day => 1,);
my $end     = DateTime->new(year => 2012, month => 1, day => 1,);
while ($counter < $end) {
    say $counter->ymd(q(-));
    # 2011-01-01
    # 2011-01-02
    # 2011-01-03
    # 2011-01-04
    # ⋮
    # 2011-12-28
    # 2011-12-29
    # 2011-12-30
    # 2011-12-31
    $counter->add(days => 1);
}
```

---

> just get the text from the online source without downloading the files

Typical [self-answered question](http://ginini.com/perlsaq.html). The function is [`get`](http://p3rl.org/LWP%3a%3aSimple#get-url-). Do read the documentation of the software you're working with.

Answer (score -2):

Perl has "for loop"s.  They will be a great way for you to try to download the files across all dates.  You will probably end up with two nested loops, one for months, and one for dates.  Learn more at:

> http://perl.about.com/od/perltutorials/a/forloop_2.htm

Please don't forget to honor copyrights, and cite references.

Comment: Thanks - I am familiar with for loops, I just do not know the format for dates in the URLS and pdfs..

Comment: This answer is unhelpful. If it were mine, I would be shamed into deleting it.